# video file: fast forward and backward doesn't work

Tags: video, forward

I have a few video clip in both flv and mp4 formats which don't fast forward or backward to arbitrary spots (time indexes).  Basically each video clip has 4 or 5 spots to which you can backward or forward, but you can't forward or backward to arbitrary time indexes. I was wondering if there is anyway to modify or convert the videos so that I can forward or backward to any time index on the video clip.

Thanks for your help

Comment: They are all under 10 minutes.

Answer (score 7):

In general, you can't seek to arbitrary time positions within a video file format such as MP4.  This is because video players rely on the container to provide file offsets for video frames that can be random-accessed, and only certain frames qualify.  (Most video frames cannot be decoded on their own, but rely on the information from several previous frames.)

However, many videos provide the *illusion* of seeking to arbitrary time positions by providing many random-access points.  In other words, the [GOP size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures) is kept small (keyframes every 1 second is typical), and these keyframes are referenced in the MP4 structure.  Your videos are probably encoded with large GOP sizes, so they have very few seek points.

I suspect that if you transcoded your videos using a tool such as [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) with default settings, you'll find that they are much more usable when seeking.